# Realtime Speaker audio - Gogole Speech to Text

Tags: audio, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I'm trying to capture real-time audio coming from the speaker through the lookback device. I want to send this audio stream to Google Speech to Text. I've done the same using the microphone (using a Google example), and it worked well. However, with the speaker, it's not working. I'm not sure how to test it properly. I'm playing a YouTube video with audio to come out of the speaker, but it returns: google.api_core.exceptions.OutOfRange: 400 Audio Timeout Error: Long duration elapsed without audio. Audio should be sent close to real-time.

I also tried simulating it through Google Meet to see if it would capture the audio from another participant coming through the speaker, but it doesn't work either. It freezes when sending to the Google Speech API. Any suggestions on how to test this? Or are these the right methods? Is there an error in my code?

Below is the code I adapted from Google, replacing the microphone with the speaker.

```
import queue
import re
import sys
import pyaudiowpatch as pyaudio
from google.cloud import speech


# Audio recording parameters
RATE = 16000
CHUNK = int(RATE / 10)  # 100ms


class MicrophoneStream:
    """Opens a recording stream as a generator yielding the audio chunks."""

    def get_speaker_config(self):
        default_speakers = None
        with pyaudio.PyAudio() as p:
            try:
                # Get default WASAPI info
                wasapi_info = p.get_host_api_info_by_type(pyaudio.paWASAPI)
            except OSError:
                print("Looks like WASAPI is not available on the system. Exiting...")
                exit()

            # Get default WASAPI speakers
            default_speakers = p.get_device_info_by_index(
                wasapi_info["defaultOutputDevice"]
            )

            if not default_speakers["isLoopbackDevice"]:
                for loopback in p.get_loopback_device_info_generator():
                    """
                    Try to find loopback device with same name(and [Loopback suffix]).
                    Unfortunately, this is the most adequate way at the moment.
                    """
                    if default_speakers["name"] in loopback["name"]:
                        default_speakers = loopback
                        break
                else:
                    print(
                        "Default loopback output device not found.\n\nRun `python -m pyaudiowpatch` to check available devices.\nExiting...\n"
                    )
                    exit()

        return default_speakers

    def __init__(self: object) -> None:
        """The audio -- and generator -- is guaranteed to be on the main thread."""

        # Create a thread-safe buffer of audio data
        self._buff = queue.Queue()
        self.closed = True
        self.default_speaker = self.get_speaker_config()
        self._rate = int(self.default_speaker["defaultSampleRate"])
        self._chunk = int(self._rate / 10)

    def __enter__(self: object) -> object:
        self._audio_interface = pyaudio.PyAudio()

        self._audio_stream = self._audio_interface.open(
            format=pyaudio.paInt16,
            channels=self.default_speaker["maxInputChannels"],
            rate=int(self.default_speaker["defaultSampleRate"]),
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=self._chunk,
            # Run the audio stream asynchronously to fill the buffer object.
            # This is necessary so that the input device's buffer doesn't
            # overflow while the calling thread makes network requests, etc.
            stream_callback=self._fill_buffer,
            input_device_index=self.default_speaker["index"],
        )

        self.closed = False

        return self

    def __exit__(
        self: object,
        type: object,
        value: object,
        traceback: object,
    ) -> None:
        """Closes the stream, regardless of whether the connection was lost or not."""
        self._audio_stream.stop_stream()
        self._audio_stream.close()
        self.closed = True

        self._buff.put(None)
        self._audio_interface.terminate()

    def _fill_buffer(
        self: object,
        in_data: object,
        frame_count: int,
        time_info: object,
        status_flags: object,
    ) -> object:
        """Continuously collect data from the audio stream, into the buffer.

        Args:
            in_data: The audio data as a bytes object
            frame_count: The number of frames captured
            time_info: The time information
            status_flags: The status flags

        Returns:
            The audio data as a bytes object
        """
        self._buff.put(in_data)
        return None, pyaudio.paContinue

    def generator(self: object) -> object:
        """Generates audio chunks from the stream of audio data in chunks.

        Args:
            self: The MicrophoneStream object

        Returns:
            A generator that outputs audio chunks.
        """
        while not self.closed:

            chunk = self._buff.get()
            if chunk is None:
                return
            data = [chunk]

            # Now consume whatever other data's still buffered.
            while True:
                try:
                    chunk = self._buff.get(block=False)
                    if chunk is None:
                        return
                    data.append(chunk)
                except queue.Empty:
                    break

            yield b"".join(data)


def listen_print_loop(responses: object) -> str:
    for response in responses:
        if not response.results:
            continue
        result = response.results[0]
        if not result.alternatives:
            continue
        transcript = result.alternatives[0].transcript
        print(transcript)


def main() -> None:
    """Transcribe speech from audio file."""
    language_code = "pt-BR" 

    with MicrophoneStream() as stream:
        client = speech.SpeechClient()
        config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
            encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
            sample_rate_hertz=stream._rate,
            language_code=language_code,
        )

        streaming_config = speech.StreamingRecognitionConfig(
            config=config, interim_results=True
        )

        audio_generator = stream.generator()
        requests = (
            speech.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=content)
            for content in audio_generator
        )

        responses = client.streaming_recognize(streaming_config, requests)

        # Now, put the transcription responses to use.
        listen_print_loop(responses)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```